# How can I make int command in boolean instead?

Tags: c#

I want to make the same as I did here, to do the same operation, but instead of doing the int first_dig and second_dig I want to use it with boolean, something like: `bool check = (new code here);`

```
           Console.Write("Enter a two digit number: ");
            int two_dig_num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (two_dig_num >= 10 && two_dig_num <= 99)
            {
                int first_dig = two_dig_num % 10;
                int second_dig = two_dig_num / 10;

                if (first_dig == second_dig)
                    Console.WriteLine("YES!");

                else
                    Console.WriteLine("NO...");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou haven't entered a Two Digit Number,\nPlease exit the program and try again later");
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You know boolean is 0 or 1, not 2-9 right

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking.  Perhaps you can demonstrate the intent with an attempt?

Comment: delete int first_dig = two_dig_num % 10; and second_dig = two_dig_num / 10; and make it like bool check = (replacement here);

Comment: what exactly are you testing for? if both numbers of your 2 digit number are the same?

Comment: Yeah, BugFinder

Comment: Then: `bool check = two_dig_num % 10 == two_dig_num / 10;`

Answer (score 1):

`first_dig == second_dig` returns you **bool**, so if you want to store it in some variable then just:

```
bool value = first_dig == second_dig;
```

or with less variables it can be:

```
bool value = two_dig_num % 10 == two_dig_num / 10;
```

That is it.